# How does wsDualHttpBinding work?

Tags: wcf

Can anybody tell me how does [wsDualHttpBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731821%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) work and what exactly is the difference between sockets and wsDualHttpBinding?

I think Microsoft did a great job. I never thought a web service would be able to call its client back again whenever it wishes. How is all this possible? I never saw any other language supporting this type of webservice, not in Java and not in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice article on idunno.org showing [an example of how to use wsDualHttpBinding](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx). It is showing you how to subscribe clients, push updates, etc.

Comment: - I already have made example by refering one msdn link. What i am asking is how does it actually work under the hood.